# Please help how to shorten the sentence with LUA pattern

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

My pattern shortens strings in the following way:

```
string.gsub("First Second Third", "%s?(.[\128-\191]*)%S+%s", "%1. ")
= "F. S. Third"
```

How can I get `"First S. T."` instead?

Very very very thanks all for answers.

Comment: `string.gsub("First Second Third", "%f[%S](.[\128-\191]*)%S+", "%1.")`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might want

```
string.gsub("First Second Third", "%s(%a)%a*", " %1.")
```

This returns

```
First S. T.
```

If it needs to be more like your pattern it would be like this, which returns the same, for this example at least. But I think the `[\128-\191]` part doesn't make much sense to me

```
string.gsub("First Second Third", "%s(.[\128-\191]*)%S+", " %1.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string.gsub("First Second Third", "(%S+)%s+(%S)%S*%s+(%S)%S*", "%1 %2. %3.")
```

The pattern selects words as runs of non-whitespace separated by runs of whitespace. It captures the first word and the first letters of the other words.